# Pandas read_html to return raw HTML contents [for certain rows/cells/etc.]

Tags: python, html, pandas, web-scraping, dataframe

Simple enough question, but I'm guessing the answer is "No":

I have a HTML table that I'm reading in with pandas.read_html just fine.  But some cells (columns) have, say, images in them, or lists, or other formatting that obviously read_html throws away.  I obviously don't expect pandas to parse any of that, but is there any way to get it to return the raw HTML as, say, a string in the cell of the DataFrame so I can parse it on my own?

EXAMPLE:

```html
<table>
    <th>Column 1</th> 
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell1</td> 
        <td>Cell2 <img src="http://www.link.com/image.jpg /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell3</td> 
        <td>Cell4 <img src="http://www.website.com/picture.gif /></td>
    </tr>          
</table>
```

If Pandas was to parse this, I'd probably just get "Cell2" and "Cell4" from column2.  What I'd like to do is somehow get the entire contents of the cell, including the [raw?] HTML contents of the `<img>` tag.  I can then parse them on my own.

Comment: Hmmm, neat example. definitely appears to me like a bug. (It turns out you were clear, it's *always* best to give an example IMO.)

Comment: Does Pandas have something like `innerHTML`?

Comment: @user770901: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: @Thomas The Pandas team is aware of this (i.e. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14608).  I don't think it's going to happen any time soon, but they do amazing work with Pandas, so I can't complain.

Comment: This is currently [pandas enhance issue #14608](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14608) without any version commitment, i.e. a neat feature looking for someone to volunteer to implement, else it will never happen. Something similar to JS's "innerHTML" [What does innerHTML do in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879066/what-does-innerhtml-do-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

There are no options for the `pd.read_html` function that do what you want. So when I tried to get a list of business names from the California Department of State website, I get everything except the name when Pandas automatically parses the HTML:

```py
>>> bizname = 'poss'
>>> url = f'https://businesssearch.sos.ca.gov/CBS/SearchResults?filing=&SearchType=CORP&SearchCriteria={bizname}&SearchSubType=Begins'
>>> df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
>>> df
  Entity Number Registration Date         Status                                        Entity Name Jurisdiction      Agent for Service of Process
0      C2645412        04/02/2004         ACTIVE  View details for entity number 02645412  POSSU...      GEORGIA   ERESIDENTAGENT, INC. (C2702827)
1      C0786330        09/22/1976      DISSOLVED  View details for entity number 00786330  POSSU...   CALIFORNIA                        I. HALPERN
2      C2334141        03/01/2001  FTB SUSPENDED  View details for entity number 02334141  POSSU...   CALIFORNIA                   CLAIR G BURRILL
3      C0658630        11/08/1972  FTB SUSPENDED  View details for entity number 00658630  POSSU...   CALIFORNIA                               NaN
4      C1713121        09/23/1992  FTB SUSPENDED  View details for entity number 01713121  POSSU...   CALIFORNIA                LAWRENCE J. TURNER
5      C1207820        08/05/1983      DISSOLVED  View details for entity number 01207820  POSSU...   CALIFORNIA                          R L CARL
6      C3921531        06/27/2016         ACTIVE  View details for entity number 03921531  POSSU...   CALIFORNIA  REGISTERED AGENTS INC (C3365816)
```

The website hides business names behind a button.
But you can use `requests` to download the raw html.
Then you can use `bs4` to extract the raw HTML table as well as any particular row (`<tr>`) or cell (`<td>`) that you want.

```py
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
>>> table = soup.find('table').findAll('tr')
>>> names = []
... for row in table:
...     names.append(getattr(row.find('button'), 'contents', [''])[0].strip())
>>> names
['',
 'POSSUM FILMS, INC',
 'POSSUM INC.',
 'POSSUM MEDIA, INC.',
 'POSSUM POINT PRODUCTIONS, INC.',
 'POSSUM PRODUCTIONS, INC.',
 'POSSUM-BILITY EXPRESS, INCORPORATED',
]
>>> df['Entity Name'] = names[1:]
>>> df['Entity Name'] = names[1:]
>>> df
  Entity Number Registration Date         Status                          Entity Name Jurisdiction      Agent for Service of Process
0      C2645412        04/02/2004         ACTIVE                    POSSUM FILMS, INC      GEORGIA   ERESIDENTAGENT, INC. (C2702827)
1      C0786330        09/22/1976      DISSOLVED                          POSSUM INC.   CALIFORNIA                        I. HALPERN
2      C2334141        03/01/2001  FTB SUSPENDED                   POSSUM MEDIA, INC.   CALIFORNIA                   CLAIR G BURRILL
3      C0658630        11/08/1972  FTB SUSPENDED       POSSUM POINT PRODUCTIONS, INC.   CALIFORNIA                               NaN
4      C1713121        09/23/1992  FTB SUSPENDED             POSSUM PRODUCTIONS, INC.   CALIFORNIA                LAWRENCE J. TURNER
5      C1207820        08/05/1983      DISSOLVED  POSSUM-BILITY EXPRESS, INCORPORATED   CALIFORNIA                          R L CARL
6      C3921531        06/27/2016         ACTIVE                      POSSUMS WELCOME   CALIFORNIA  REGISTERED AGENTS INC (C33658
```

Doing it this way doesn't process the header correctly, so don't forget to ignore the first row, if you need to.