# Read image alt text with pandas.read_html

Tags: python, html, pandas

Is there a way using `pandas.read_html` to get the `img alt` text from an image ? The page I am scrapping just replaced some texts with pictures, and the old text is now the `alt` text for those images. Here is an example:

```
<td>
<div>...
<a href="/index.php/WF..." title="WF"><img alt="WFrag" src="/images/thumb/WF.png" </a>
</div>
</td>
```

This is how it looked, and it was perfect for `pandas.read_html`

```
<td>
WF
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the thread linked to in the previous answer, `read_html` is designed only for tables with text content and isn't able to parse `<a>`, `<div>`, `<img>`, etc. You'll need to preprocess the HTML you get from scraping before passing it to `read_html`.

If you're in the market for a quick and dirty solution, you could do this using regex:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

table_html = """
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
<a href="/index.php/WF..." title="WF"><img alt="WFrag" src="/images/thumb/WF.png" </a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>"""

# Delete all <div>, </div>, <a> and </a> tags
table_html = re.sub(r'</?div[^>]*>', '', table_html)
table_html = re.sub(r'</?a[^>]*>', '', table_html)
# Replace <img> tags with the content of their alt attribute
table_html = re.sub(r'<img[^>]*alt="([^"]*)"[^>]*>', r'\1', table_html)

print(pd.read_html(table_html))
```

Outputs:

```
[       0
0  WFrag]
```

However this is not a very robust solution as it may need to be adapted to any irregular output (if a tag was written  in capital letters for example). A better way would be to parse the HTML string and perform the same operations with a library specifically designed for parsing HTML, such as [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is not possible with pandas.
You can check out the answer in this thread
[Pandas read_html to return raw HTML contents [for certain rows/cells/etc.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236870/pandas-read-html-to-return-raw-html-contents-for-certain-rows-cells-etc)