# small javascript to output options to a select doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im making a small webpage. The goal is simple. I have a select with a few options; it is planet names; and their sizes are placed in the value bracket of each option. What i want to do is upon selecting an option ( a planet ), a javascript code will take the choice's size, and give new options to another select bracket. So depending on the first select , the second select bracket will be given new options.

The code is simple and ive overwatched it but theres no error.

I just dont get what's not working. Here's the code:

```
<select id="selectedplanet" name="selectedplanet" onchange="jcab3();">

<?php 
while($fetch28a3=mysqli_fetch_array($query28a3)){
echo('<option value="'.$fetch28a3[1].'">'.$fetch28a3[0].'</option>');
}?>
</select><br/>
<p>Location: </p><br/><br/><p>X:</p><select id="locationx" name="locationX"></select><br/><p>Y:</p><select id="locationy" name="locationY"></select>
```

This is the html/php side. As you can see , I summon a php that fetch some datas from a mysql table. It assign new options on a select bracket. The select has an 'onchange' , which summon the javascript function 'jcab3' upon changing the select . Then here's the javascript:

```
function jcab3(){
   var final2="";
   var final3="";

   var prima=parseInt(document.getElementById("selectedplanet").value);

   for(i31=0;i31<prima;i31++){
       final2=final2+'<option value="'+i31+'">'+i31+'</option>';

   }
    for(i32=0;i32<prima;i32++){
        final3=final3+'<option value="'+i32+'">'+i32+'</option>';
        }
        document.getElementById("locationx").innerHTML=final2;
        document.getElementById("locationy").innerHTML=final3;

}
```

basically, it takes the size of the planet, then give out new options from 0 to the planet's size , and should place these new options under 2 differents select brackets ( 'locationx' and 'locationy'). But , it just doesnt work.

can anyone help ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<select id="myplanet">
    <option value="4">Earth</option>
    <option value="5">Mars</option>
    <option  value="6">JUpiter</option>
</select>

<p>X:</p>
<select id="locationx" name="locationX"></select><br/>
<p>Y:</p>
<select id="locationy" name="locationY"></select>

<script>

  document.getElementById("myplanet").addEventListener('change', function(){
  var e = document.getElementById("myplanet");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var prima =  parseInt( value )
    var final2="";
    var final3="";
    for(i31=0;i31<prima;i31++){
       final2=final2+'<option value="'+i31+'">'+i31+'</option>';

    }
    for(i32=0;i32<prima;i32++){
        final3=final3+'<option value="'+i32+'">'+i32+'</option>';
    }

    document.getElementById("locationx").innerHTML = final2
    document.getElementById("locationy").innerHTML = final3


  })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but i never learnt jquery... 

i thought javascript is enough for what i need .

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now it is using only javascript, no jquery . if it is helpful, can you please vote my answer

Comment: thanks a lot. I already upvoted your answer. I will look to the 2 replies and decided which is my favorite. 

but thanks again

Answer (score 0):

How many new `<option>`s tags are you adding into your `<select>`s?

Consider that as saying by @Michael Bogwardt in his comment about [what innerHTML is doing in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879066/what-innerhtml-is-doing-in-javascript):

> However, DOM manipulations using innerHTML are slower and more
>   failure-prone than manipulations based on individual DOM objects.

Would be better to create your `<option>`s tags by using `element.appendChild()` and `element.setAttribute()` functions. Your code could look like this:

```
function jcab3(){
   var prima=parseInt(document.getElementById("selectedplanet").value);

   var x = document.getElementById("locationx");
   var y = document.getElementById("locationy");

   for(i31=0;i31<prima;i31++){

     var option = x.appendChild("OPTION");
     option.setAttribute("value", i31); 

   }

   for(i32=0;i32<prima;i32++){

     var option = y.appendChild("OPTION");
     option.setAttribute("value", i32); 

   }    
}
```